# Using Python to create comments on Google Sites

Tags: python, google-sites

I'm migrating a site into Google Sites and am having a hard time creating the standard Google Sites comments on pages.  I've been able to create the site and create pages within the site, but now need to create comments for those pages.

Here's what I have so far:

```
new_entry = self.client.CreatePage('webpage', 'this is my page title', 'page body')
new_comment = self.client.CreatePage('comment', 'comment title', 'comment body', parent = new_entry)
```

This does create the page correctly and it does seem to create a comment somewhere (it doesn't error out), but when I view the page the comment isn't listed.  If I add in `print new_comment` it does print out a bunch of stuff, so it's somewhere.

I was not able to find any specific method for creating a comment and noticed that CreatePage can take 'comment' as the first argument and figured I'd put the page the comment is for in the parent argument but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Please tell me that you are not attempting to create a spam bot.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Signus, The Sites API doesn't support comments ever since the service updated to the Google Drive version of commenting. Google hasn't fixed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/reference) yet, but you can't add/retrieve/delete comments with the API or any client library.